# How to loop through json object, which has been converted to associative array, to get prop value

Tags: php, associative-array

I am using PHP (I am a noob) to retrieve a file from the local server. This is a json file. I then convert this into an associative array. However I am having issues with looping through the properties and arrays, to target the value I need.

Below is what each element of the array looks like, and I trying to target the iso2 and name property/values of each country.

```
array (
  'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
  'features' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'type' => 'Feature',
      'properties' => 
      array (
        **'name' => 'Bahamas',
        'iso_a2' => 'BS',**
        'iso_a3' => 'BHS',
        'iso_n3' => '044',
      ),
      'geometry' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'MultiPolygon',
        'coordinates' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.53466,
                1 => 23.75975,
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.78,
                1 => 23.71,
              ),
              2 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.03405,
                1 => 24.28615,
              ),
              3 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.40848,
                1 => 24.57564,
              ),
              4 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.19087,
                1 => 25.2103,
              ),
              5 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.89,
                1 => 25.17,
              ),
              6 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.54,
                1 => 24.34,
              ),
              7 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.53466,
                1 => 23.75975,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.82,
                1 => 26.58,
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.91,
                1 => 26.42,
              ),
              2 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.98,
                1 => 26.79,
              ),
              3 => 
              array (
                0 => -78.51,
                1 => 26.87,
              ),
              4 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.85,
                1 => 26.84,
              ),
              5 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.82,
                1 => 26.58,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                0 => -77,
                1 => 26.59,
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.17255,
                1 => 25.87918,
              ),
              2 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.35641,
                1 => 26.00735,
              ),
              3 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.34,
                1 => 26.53,
              ),
              4 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.78802,
                1 => 26.92516,
              ),
              5 => 
              array (
                0 => -77.79,
                1 => 27.04,
              ),
              6 => 
              array (
                0 => -77,
                1 => 26.59,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Here is how I am trying to access the array, but to no avail

```
forEach($assArr["features"] as $element){
    if ($element[0]["properties"]["iso_a2"] == "BS"){
        echo_r($element[0]);
    }
}
```

What the page outputs
*"Undefined offset: 0"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$element` will refer to the values inside already.

```php
forEach($assArr["features"] as $element){
    if ($element["properties"]["iso_a2"] == "BS"){
        echo_r($element);
    }
}
```

If you need the 0, you can do the following

```php
forEach($assArr["features"] as $key => $element){
    if ($element["properties"]["iso_a2"] == "BS"){
        echo_r($key); // will be 0
        echo_r($element);
    }
}
```